# How to get dynamic node and element values in xml using vb?

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to vb. In my XML file all the attributes, nodes and elements are dynamic([Healthcare.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3pkx.png)). I am trying to get the values in the below manner.

page: login, method: login, args: ad59090,GA124444

In some cases, there will be multiple methods and arguments.

page: benefits, method: tagbenefits,args: benefit1,benefit2 (This benefit page have muliple methods)

page: benefits, method: clickonEOC,args: nothing

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<pages>

<page id="login">
<method name="login">
<step>I want to login to CCB application</step>
<args id="username">
<value>ad59090</value>
</args>
<args id="password">
<value>GA124444</value>
</args>
</method>
</page>

<page id="benefits">
<method name="tagbenefits">
<step>I want to tag benefits on benefit page</step>
<args id="benefit1">
<value>General benefits</value>
</args>
<args id="benefit2">
<value>Cancer</value>
</args>
</method>
<method name="cleabenefits">
<step>I want to clear tag benefits on benefit page</step>
<args id="benefit1">
<value>General benefits</value>
</args>
<args id="benefit2">
<value>Cancer</value>
</args>
</method>
<method name="clickonEOC">
<step>I want to click on EOC page</step>
</method>
</page>

<page id="claims">
<method name="tagclaims">
<step>I want to tag claims on claims page</step>
<args id="claim1">
<value>201234567899</value>
</args>
<args id="claim2">
<value>201234567897</value>
</args>
</method>
<method name="clickonclaimpaymentlink">
<step>I want to navigate to claims payment page</step>
<args id="claim">
<value>201234567825</value>
</args>
</method>
<method name="validateclaimnumber">
<step>I want to DCN number on claim payment detail page</step>
<args> 
<value>201234567897</value>
</args>
</method>
</page>

</pages>
```

I am struck to do this. As of now i have tried with 3 for loops to get the values (Page -> Method -> args) but this is not working.

First loop: Getting the number of page nodes

Second loop: Trying to get the number of methods under each page (But selecting all the methods in entire XML)

Third loop: Gettig the number of arguments under particular method
[Code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjzYA.png)

Vb code:

```
Set Root = objXMLDoc.DocumentElement
Set NodeList = Root.getElementsByTagName("page")
Set List2 = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//page")
Set List = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//page/method") 'Here it is selecting all the methods in XML.
                                               'It should select the methods under page1

For Each node2 In List2
Set Pageid = node2.Attributes.getNamedItem("id")
MsgBox (Pageid.Text)


For Each node In List
Set methodname = node.Attributes.getNamedItem("name")
MsgBox (methodname.Text)


For Each Elem In NodeList
Set idlist = Elem.getElementsByTagName("value")

For j = 0 To idlist.Length - 1
Set arg = Elem.getElementsByTagName("value")(j)
Msg = Msg + "," + arg.Text & vbNewLine
Next
MsgBox (Msg)
Exit For

Next

Next
```

Could you please suggest an approach to achieve this?

Comment: VBA or VBScript? (they are not the same thing) - And some people cannot see pictures of your code, so instead, please include your code as part of your question so people can also copy/paste it if they need to in order to answer your question.

Comment: @braX updated with code!

Comment: Read the XML as a text file and use "Select.. Case condition"

Comment: @nishitdey Hi nishit, can you please post an example to be more clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution!

First, used multiple loops to get the pages and method.

Next, final loop to get the arguments. Below is the code.

```
Sub Type2()
Dim xmlDoc As New DOMDocument
Dim Root
Dim NodeList
Dim Msg
Dim arg
Dim myStringArray() As String
Dim methodname
Dim finalmsg As String
xmlDoc.async = False
Dim node As IXMLDOMNode
Dim node2 As IXMLDOMNode
Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim L As Integer
L = 2
k = 1
i = 0

Set objXMLDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
objXMLDoc.async = False

xmlDoc.Load ("C:\Users\Sifv\Desktop\XML\DummyXML.xml")
objXMLDoc.Load ("C:\Users\Sifv\Desktop\XML\DummyXML.xml")

'Getting the number of page and method nodes
Set Root = objXMLDoc.DocumentElement
Set NodeList = Root.getElementsByTagName("page")
Set NodeList2 = Root.getElementsByTagName("method")

'Three for loops to get pages and methods
For k = 0 To NodeList.Length

Set List2 = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//page[" & k & "]")
Set List = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//page[" & k & "]/method")

For Each node2 In List2
Set Pageid = node2.Attributes.getNamedItem("id")
'MsgBox (Pageid.Text)

For Each node In List
Set methodname = node.Attributes.getNamedItem("name")
'MsgBox (methodname.Text)

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Cells(L, 1).Value = Pageid.Text
Cells(L, 2).Value = methodname.Text
L = L + 1
Next

Next

Next

'Final for loop to get the list of arguments under each method
L = 2
For Each Elem In NodeList2
Set idlist = Elem.getElementsByTagName("value")
'MsgBox (NodeList2.Length)
'MsgBox (idlist.Length)

For j = 0 To idlist.Length - 1
Set arg = Elem.getElementsByTagName("value")(j)
Msg = Msg + "," + arg.Text
Next j
'MsgBox (Msg)

If idlist.Length = 0 Then
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Cells(L, 3).Value = "No Arguments"
L = L + 1

Else
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Cells(L, 3).Value = "'" + Right(Msg, Len(Msg) - 1)
L = L + 1
End If

'MsgBox (Msg)
Msg = vbStringNull

Next


End Sub
```

Below is the out put.

[Excel output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwUoU.png)